# Qt throws error when allocating too much dynamic memory within a class

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, new-operator

I have a class where I allocate some memory. For Example:

```
class image {

public:
    image(){
        pixelvalue = 0;
    }

    void formatandcopy() {
        pixelvalue = new int [10000*50000];
        if(pixelvalue)
            qDebug()<<"allocation successful"; 
        else 
            qDebug()<<"allocation failed";
    }
private:
    int *pixelvalue;
};
```

When I call `formatandcopy()` the program throws this:

```
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.
```

Anyone know how I can prevent this and let the user know it's simply out of memory? When I run this it doesn't even show `allocation failed`. The above error is thrown before the `qDebug()` is called. The program runs fine if the amount of memory allocated is decreased. I thought this was strange since this error is thrown when using the `new` operator and not a qt function. Furthermore my machine has plenty of memory left. I assume this is a result of qt limiting it's program to a certain heap space. Lastly, if I can fix this by indeed reimplementing the `notify` function then can anyone point me in the right direction to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing that you could re-implement QApplication::notify() and catch the ecxeption there ... just a guess you understand ...

Comment: The fix here is to figure out why your program is trying to allocate too much memory and preventing it to begin with.  I don't want to see a messagebox telling me the program ran out of memory without be accompanied by a workable solution.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Right now the error is occuring because I'm loading a jpg which "uncompresses" it and stores each pixel value in an array. I need the pixel values for some image processing I'm doing. As of now, I don't anticipate needing really large images (like 10,000x10,000 pixels) but I'd like to implement a safe guard if someone decides to load a large image like that. In the future I'll consider implementing function which either breaks up the image or interpolates the image to a smaller size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to catch **[std::bad_alloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/bad_alloc/)** to handle the exception within that function.  The exception is part of standard C++.

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (std::bad_alloc &a) {
  // ...
}
```

If it gets beyond that scope (into the Qt event handling) then you will have to implement `QApplication::notify` as they specify.

As a word of warning, bad allocations usually are not recoverable.  The exception is when you know you are allocating a very large amount (perhaps based on user input) when you typically will not be using a very memory hungry application.

EDIT:

To clarify, if the design of your application allows you to run out of memory, then it is unlikely that anything will change if you catch bad_allocs and ignore them.  The program is dead, you are only going to be able to display an error message about what happened.  That is also tricky, because you cannot allocate any memory to create the message box!

The counter example is a scenario like asking the user for a file and reading it all into memory.  Eventually they will try and give you a file that they don't have the memory for and you can safely tell them to try another file.  These sorts of problems are usually isolated in an application and well worth guarding against.

Comment: Tom, it seems like all dynamic memory allocations should be in a `try-catch` block. Would there be any disadvantages to having a function which takes in a pointer and allocates memory to it within a `try-catch` block?

Comment: @user1346994 try/catch blocks also incur *some* overhead, though usually you shouldn't worry about that.  It makes code harder to read, especially given that you won't be able to do anything about a bad_alloc other than ignore it.

Comment: @user1346994 I updated the answer a little bit, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what has happened and what to do:  Exceptions cannot propagate out of an event handler (or anything inside a signal/slot mechanism), in order for exceptions to be handled properly they have to be caught inside `QApplication::notify()`, like this:

```
bool MyApplication::notify( QObject* receiver, QEvent* event )
{
    try {
        return QApplication::notify( receiver, event );
    } catch ( std::exception& e ) {
        cout << "Arrrgggghhhh" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, it's your OS that decides how much heap space you can have, not Qt.

Comment: Thank you. I'll test this out. Also thanks for noting that it's the OS that limits heap space and not Qt.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check `pixelvalue` integrity by doing `if(pixelvalue)`, if `new` fails an exception is thrown and the pointer isn't allocated anywhere so `pixelvalue` doesn't exists, thus its useless to check the integrity of a pointer that doesn't exists. Use it if you want to check if it isn't a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: pixelvalue is initialized to point to 0 in the constructor. Is it still true that if an allocation fails pixelvalue will not point anywhere?

Comment: @Amani: This should be a comment; @user1346994: if the `new` operator fails, it throws an exception so you never even get to test the pointer value.

Comment: As I'm a new user I can only comment my own posts